# Disconnect TwythonStreamer on DELETE rest api call

Tags: python, rest, tornado, twitter-streaming-api, twython

Here is my wrapper on TwythonStreamer:

```
from twython import TwythonStreamer

class Twitter_talker(TwythonStreamer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Twitter_talker, self).__init__(<my credentials here...>)
    def on_success(self, data):
        self.disconnect()
        print data

    def on_error(self, status_code, data):
        print status_code
        self.disconnect()
```

Here is my call to get statuses from twitter:

```
class Tweet_Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    stream = Twitter_talker()
    stream.statuses.filter(track='badminton')
```

I create this stream looking for "badminton" on GET REST API call to my web server. And though its not coded, but it will be a async call, meaning i will return a response like "1" indicating stream was created successfully.

How do I *`self.disconnect`* when i receive a DELETE REST API call with value "badminton" ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `DELETE` handler will have a different `self` than your `GET` handler (a new `RequestHandler` is always instantiated for each request.  You'll need to store the `GET` handler somewhere, perhaps a global dictionary mapping keywords to a set of handlers (don't forget to remove it in `on_finish`).  Look at the Tornado [chat demo](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/chat/chatdemo.py) and how it manages the set of waiters.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class attribute to hold a dictionary of Twitter Talkers.

```
class Tweet_Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    requests = {}

    def get(self):
        stream = Twitter_talker()
        stream.statuses.filter(track='badminton')
        Tweet_Handler.requests['badminton'] = stream

    def delete(self):
        value = self.get_argument("value")
        if value in Tweet_Handler.requests:
             Tweet_Handler.requests[value].disconnect()
             del Tweet_Handler.requests[value]
```